# Show the count of greater than average items

Tags: sql, oracle

First, this is for homework so if I cant ask, my apologies. I feel like I should not be asking this but having the darndest time trying to get this to work. What I am trying to do is pull the count of the different types of beers and associate them with their respective brewery. From here I will display the counts that are above the average number of beers at a location. Also, if they have the same amount of beers to then filter by the name.

EDIT here are the tables

Beers
[image: Beers]

Brewery[image: Brewery Table]

```
SELECT      --Displays on table

        NAME AS "Brewer", 
        country AS "Country",
        COUNT(beer_ID) AS "Amount"
        
FROM       --connects the two tables by ID--
        BEERDB.beers LEFT OUTER JOIN
        BEERDB.breweries
            ON breweries.brewery_ID = beers.brewery_ID           
 
           
WHERE        
       --Trying to find breweries that are not in the United states and thought this would create a 
       --formula where the beer_ID would change to the count of that column not the contents
    
        country NOT LIKE 'UNITED STATES'
        AND count(beerdb.beers.beer_id) >
        (SELECT avg((Count(beer_ID))
        FROM Beerdb.beers
        )

GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY    --Orders by the count and then name if matched
        
        count(beers.beer_id), breweries.name ASC;
```

Comment: Not a problem asking for help with homework.  Just don't expect people to actually do your work for you.  You don't appear to be asking that, so good for you.  Now to your problem. Can you write code for tables when you don't know the table definitions?  Neither can we.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Data should be provided as text tables and/or SQL CREATE statements, not images. Make it easier for readers to replicate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask